# Non-cyclic finite extensions of fixed fields of infinite order automorphisms of non-algebraically closed fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

This is a problem from Galois theory:

> Suppose that $F$ is algebraically closed, $\lambda$ is an automorphism of infinite order, and $f=F^\lambda$. Show that any finite extension of $f$ is cyclic.

What is an example of $F$ which is not algebraically closed so the conclusion fails?

Can these examples be characterize in some way?

Comment: I would imagine you could find a counterexample by taking $\mathbb Q(\{x_i\}_{i\in \mathbb Z})$  and looking at the fixed field of the automorphism generated by $x_i \mapsto x_{i+1}$. I don't have time to work through the details, but I believe the fixed field is $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @JSchlather You should write that as an answer, even if incomplete!

Comment: @Marie Probably. I wanted to write it up for a field $k$ with a finite non-cyclic extension and any infinite set $S$, but was struggling with a few details. I'm really curious now about finding a counterexample where the extension $F/F^{\lambda}$ is algebraic. Although I think with some care an example could be constructed by looking at an infinite order automorphism of $\mathbb Q^{\mathrm{ab}}$. Then any non-abelian irreducible polynomial $p(x)$ should give rise to a non-cyclic extension of whatever the fixed field is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filling in the details of the counterexample suggested by Jacob's comment:

> Write $\mathbb{Q}\left(\{x_i\}_{i\in \mathbb{Z}}\right)$ as $\mathbb{Q}(x_\mathbb{Z})$. Note that $x^2-x_i=0$ has no root in $\mathbb{Q}(x_\mathbb{Z})$, so $\mathbb{Q}(x_\mathbb{Z})$ is not algebraically closed.  Let $\sigma:\mathbb{Q}(x_\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}(x_\mathbb{Z})$ be the automorphism defined by $\sigma:x_i\rightarrow x_{i+1}$.  Then $\sigma^r:x_i\mapsto x_{i+r}$ is the identity map only when $r=0$, so $\sigma$ has infinite order. Take any rational polynomial $f\in \mathbb{Q}(x_\mathbb{Z})$.  If $f$ is a constant polynomial (that is, $f\in \mathbb{Q}$), then certainly $\sigma(f)=f$.  If $f$ is not a constant polynomial, then let $m_f$ denote the lowest index in $\mathbb{Z}$ of a variable appearing in $f$ with a nonzero coefficient.  Then, by assumption, the lowest index of a variable appearing in $\sigma(f)$ with a nonzero coefficient is $m_f+1$.  It follows that $\sigma(f)\ne f$, so $\mathbb{Q}(x_\mathbb{Z})^\sigma=\mathbb{Q}$.  Of course, not every finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ is cyclic.

Comment: This argument of course goes through for any field $k$ with a finite non-cyclic extension. It also follows immediately that $\mathbb Q(x_\mathbb Z)$ is not algebraically closed because you've only adjoined transcendental elements to a non-algebraically closed field. I'm also not entirely convinced by what you've written. It's probably simple but I got stuck on the proof that a rational function $f/g$ was not fixed by the automorphism.